# Ruby error Homebrew uninstall while having macports

Tags: ruby, git, homebrew

I installed ruby via `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and did `rvm install 1.9.2` doing this creates and error

```
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master 
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
```

Upon doing a `which git` it shows it's installed in `/usr/bin/git` yeah homebrew keeps trying to reference `/usr/local/.git`. I tried unistalling homebrew so I can do a fresh install using what's listed at [homebrew gist](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223). All seemed well but doing a `which brew` still shows it as `/usr/local/bin/brew` so I tried to manually uninstall it by doing it one by one.

One thing to note is I never had a Cellar folder, why I don't know. While doing a `brew prune` I noticed a lot of macport items are starting to ask if I should override them.

Is it typical to of ran the uninstall script but still have the brew commands available or the dirs?

Why is it that homebrew needs root access to `/user/local/` to work, this is extremely bad.

Comment: What does `echo $GIT_DIR` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `/usr/local/.git` it's referencing is not the `git` executable, but the config file for the repository it's trying to set up under `/usr/local/`. It's trying to write to that file.

To run homebrew you need write permissions to `/usr/local` as the user you'r going to run `brew` as. Homebrew's recommended method is to adjust the ownership and permissions on /usr/local to allow you to write to it from your regular user account or a dedicated homebrew account, instead of using `sudo`. This is done as part of the homebrew installation script, typically by putting you in the `admin` group and making `/usr/local` group-writable.

To fix this, check the owner and permissions on `/usr/local/` and `/usr/local/.git` and make sure you can write to them (and the rest of the `/usr/local/` hierarchy) as the user that you're running `brew` and `RVM` commands as.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up having to do, make `/usr/local/` writable, which is not a very safe method to do, poor way for brew to recommend installing.

Comment: @Bankzilla And low and behold, Homebrew has finally admitted fault on this and in the new version released a week or two ago, has restored the default permissions to /usr/local

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just doing a `sudo $USER` as I really could not find any other approach to fixing this.